# How to input/type buttons on posts?

Tags: support, formatting

I have tried multiple times to find the "button" button in order to convert e.g. `Ctrl-Alt-F1` to button sequence. Can anyone help me? I tried to find it in the desktop version of Ask Ubuntu and on the Stack Exchange Android app.

Comment: This is probably better to ask on AskUbuntu Meta.